# Program to find sum up-to .....nth number

Tags: c

1.2^2+2.3^2+3.4^2+4.5^2+  need to calculate the sum up-to nth number with C programming.
But I can't find any way to solve the program.

When the user in put 4 as the value of n, the sum will be the total of 1.2^2+2.3^2+3.4^2+4.5^2.

Can anyone help me get the algorithm?

Comment: Do you know how to set up a `for` loop? Also, presumably you mean a power series, `^` is XOR in C. But, check there's not a *closed-form* solution to this first.

Comment: I try with this 
total=pow((n*(n+1)/2),2) + 2*(n*(n+1)*(2*n+1))/6 + n*(n+1)/2
but I don't know, why output is wrong.
I got this law from internet

Comment: I tried with this.
    {#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
 int n;
 
 scanf("%d,",&n);
 
 //pow(n,2)*pow((n+1),2)/4 +n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/3 + n*(n+1)/2;
  
  int total=pow((n*(n+1)/2),2) + 2*(n*(n+1)*(2*n+1))/6 + n*(n+1)/2;
 
 printf("%d",total);
      }
}

Comment: There **is** a closed form for this: don't use a loop.

Comment: @Sudarshan Please edit your post and put your attempts inside code formatting so we can actually read it. Also, posting your attempts so far, even if they aren't working, is a good way to avoid down votes for lack of research effort.

Comment: [a = n*(n-1)*(n+1)*(3*n+2)/12](http://oeis.org/A052149)

Comment: OK. I did this and working well.

Comment: To avoid overflow for `n>=174`, use either `return (long long)n*(n+1)*(3*n+2)*(n-1)/12;` or `return (n&1) ? n*(n+1)*(n-1)/12 * (3*n+2) : n*(n+1)*(n-1)/6 * ((3*n+2)/2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for loop would do it:

```
int compute(int n) {   
  int i, sum=0;

  for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
     int val = i*(i+1)*(i+1);
     sum += val;
  } 
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Please give me fish.

Comment: The expression `int val = i*(i+1)*(i+1);` seems incorrect.

Comment: @chqrlie It seems from the author's question and comments, that the "." is used to denote multiplication and not the decimal point in his intended summation.

Comment: Trivial edit so I can reverse my downvote. This answer is correct, if inefficient.

Comment: Ooops! you are correct.  I did suspect the question to be misformulated.  The OP wants to compute the sum of cubes minus the sum of squares. Direct answer is: `return n*n*(n+1)*(n+1)/4 - n*(n+1)(2*n+1)/6;` which can be further simplified.

Comment: @chqrlie In that case, can you please retract your down vote  (if it is yours) ?

Comment: @sray: not my down vote.  Given the correct interpretation of the OP's question, +1 for the correct answer.  The answer can be computed directly and simplified as `return (n-1)*n*(n+1)*(3*n+2)/12;` for `n >= 0`.  This formula will quickly overflow 32 bits, computing it as `long long` will give a few more correct values.

Answer (score 1):

- `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`. This is a for loop.
- Inside the loop, store the loop iterator `i` in a double variable.
- Add 1.2 to it.
- Multiply it by itself.
- Do something with the result: print it, and/or add it to a sum variable etc.
- Do not use the xor operator `^` for this.

Comment: +1 for teaching someone how to fish. (But do note there is a closed-form solution for this *particular* series).

Comment: The OP's question is not stated clearly, but I doubt your advice addresses the problem. The sequence seems to be: 1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 5.4...  not 1.2, 2.2, 3.2...  But the actual question might be much simpler: sum of consecutive squares.

Comment: Why not `for (float i = 1.2f; i < n+1; i+=1.1f)`?

Comment: More something like: `double x, sum = 0.0; int i; for (i = 0, x = 1.2; i < n; i++, x += 1.1) sum += x * x;`

Comment: @chqrlie: This again duplicates the calculations, and is *less* readable. The only way it could be faster is if floating-point comparisons are very expensive.

Comment: @EOF: As suspected, the OP's question was misformulated, the floating point increment of 1.1 is bogus.  Btw your formula was incorrect because you compare compare `i` to `n` with an increment of `1.1`.  if `n=10`, you are going to perform only `9` iterations instead of `10`... hence my separate variables for iterating and testing.

Comment: @EOF Never use float variables as loop iterators, because of floating point inaccuracy. Always use an int.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. By the time rounding turns this loop infinite, the sum has already lost *a lot* more precision. I'd rather have a check before the loop to catch unreasonably large `n`.

Comment: @EOF It doesn't have anything to do with accumulated errors. In this case, suppose `n+1` translates to something like `2.299999`. Then you'd get one iteration too many because of floating point inaccuracy.